# Where to place webpack.config.js in create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have been instructed to put some instructions inside the webpack.config.js file.
However in my create-react-app project I cannot find that file.
Currently the available answer on StackOverFlow requires ejecting the project which I think will break my project.
Is it possible to use webpack.config.js inside a create-react-app project without ejecting?
Where is the webpack.config.js file? or where should I put it?

Comment: Create react app suggests [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/) as a way to configure your app without having to eject ([Source](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack config used by create-react-app is here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/config

Answer (score 4):

create-react-app hides the config files from you. If you want to modify them, you have to run `npm run eject`. This will place them under the `config/` folder.

Please read this before you do this, as this isn't a reversible action: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject

Comment: As much as possible I want to avoid ejecting....as I don't know how to work with a ejected project.....is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You would probably want to use [Craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco). It allows you to override create-react-app configurations. Other than that `eject` is a good option and it doesn't suppose to break your app

Comment: How to add this webpack instructions in Craco?    {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: false,
            publicPath: 'assets'
          },
          type:'javascript/auto'
        }